# How to use wc.pageturner in Plone 4.1?

Tags: python, plone

I have installed swftools in my linux debian version 6. In the plone buildout.cfg, added the product wc.pageturner and compiled it. In the plone site control panel - I have also activated the add-on. But when I upload a pdf and try to view using the display tab's page turner item, it displays the info that

> 'Since you do not have swftools installed on this system, we can not
>   render the pages of this PDF.'

Is anything missing. I am referring the url : http://plone.org/products/wc.pageturner . I have installed the dependancy swftools using the command `apt-get -t wheezy install swftools`

Comment: If you want a pdf viewer, use collective.documentviewer. I am no longer updating wc.pageturner--collective.documentviewer is a much better viewer and implementation.

Comment: @vangheem, is there a setting to disable printing/ copying in this viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wc.pageturner` package uses the `pdf2swf` command-line tool to do the work. However, the `swftools` package on Debian [does *not* include that tool](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/swftools):

> This package does not include pdf2swf and avi2swf.

I suspect the binary violates Debian Free Software guidelines somehow. I have not been able to locate a Debian package that *does* include the binary.

You can [install the package from source](http://wiki.swftools.org/wiki/Installation) instead.

Comment: Installed the correct pdf2swf, but alfter building plone again, and uploading a new pdf, i am not able to get the pdf page turner view at all. Please guide

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the package itself; 'not able to get the pdf page turner view at all' is rather a vague statement as well.

Comment: the pdf which is uploaded cannot be displayed as Page Turner, when the display tab item 'Page Turner' is selected. Nor does the 'Page turner Settings' changed nor the 'Flexpaper convert' tab when clicked have any effect.I don't get the display of the pdf file. Pl. advise

Comment: Again, I am not familiar enough with the package to be much help. Check the error log output (the Zope startup section, when you upload a new PDF, and when you try to view those tabs) for any clues as to what might be wrong. Have you tried any other PDFs as well?

Comment: there is an error log, but i don't know how to resolve it :INFO wc.pageturner Running command /usr/local/bin/pdf2swf /tmp/tmp1nt4bj -o /tmp/tmp8zY38s -T 9 -f -t -G  
------2012-09-14T06:24:26 INFO wc.pageturner Finished Running Command /usr/local/bin/pdf2swf /tmp/tmp1nt4bj -o /tmp/tmp8zY38s -T 9 -f -t -G  ------2012-09-14T06:24:26 ERROR wc.pageturner Error converting PDF: ERROR   Couldn't open /tmp/tmp1nt4bj None------
2012-09-14T06:24:26 ERROR wc.pageturner Error converting PDF
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: File "/home/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/wc.pageturner-1.3.2-py2.6.egg/wc/pageturner/convert.py", line 132, in convert
    password=settings.encryption_password)
  File "/home/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/wc.pageturner-1.3.2-py2.6.egg/wc/pageturner/convert.py", line 77, in convert
    raise Exception(output) Exception: ERROR   Couldn't open /tmp/tmp1nt4bj

Comment: Nope, no idea. Presumably the PDF is not password protected in any way?